# Get <img>-SRC out of <content:encoded> (xsl - RSS Viewer WP)

Tags: xslt, content, rss

I need to get the image source out of this code:

```
<content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[
        <span><img width="200" src="..."></span><br /> [some Text] ]]>
</content:encoded>
```

This is what I tried:

```
 <xsl:variable name="ImageURL" select="substring-before(substring-after(content, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;&gt;')" />
 <img alt="" src="{$ImageURL}" width="75" height="49" />
```

Unfortunately my solutions failed. I also tried some other syntax but the main part was the same. Could anybody help me please?

Thanks for all effort!

Comment: <item> <title><![CDATA[ ... ]]></title> <link></link> <content:encoded> <![CDATA[ <span><img width="200" src="..."></span><br />]]> </content:encoded> <pubDate></pubDate> <category>feed_theme</category> <author></author> <guid> This is one feeditem what "namespace" do you mean? Or do you mean the feedURL? </guid> </item>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xslt should be something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageURL" xmlns:content="http://namespaceurl" select="substring-before(substring-after(content:encoded, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
<img alt="" src="{$ImageURL}" width="75" height="49" />
```

Where `http://namespaceurl` matches the namespace "url" of `content` from the input

To find that namespace url look at the input xml it'll define the `xmlns:content` somewhere like this:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
```

If this is how it's defined then `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/` is the namespace url and your xslst should contain:

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageURL" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" select="substring-before(substring-after(content:encoded, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
<img alt="" src="{$ImageURL}" width="75" height="49" />
```

Comment: Please look at my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But the namespaceurl looks different in my xml source. I have this one:

```
rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
```

Then, follow the solution, I use:

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageURL" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"  select="substring-before(substring-after(atom:encoded, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
<li>
   <img alt="" src="{$ImageURL}" width="60" height="60" />
</li>
```

But when I see the code for the web page, I have:

```
<li> 
  <img alt="" src="" width="60" height="60" />
</li>
```

Comment: Could you please provide us the sourcecode of your IMG-Tag you try to read out?